# Android:print tasks&activities stack

Tags: android, android-activity

is there a nice way to show all of the tasks&activities stack of the current app ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must see [ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html)
There are some useful fields (numActivities, topActivity)